# Can't allow my app to use draw over other apps permission

Tags: android, android-manifest, kotlin, android-permissions

I forgot to add the permission in the manifest.

Solved

---

**Original Question**

I'm developing a little app which allows UX testers to get informations from user's input in android.

For this, I need to create a transparent view in top of all others.
I try to get the permission this way :

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    val REQUEST_CODE = 10101

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (checkDrawOverlayPermission()) {
            //startService(Intent(this, TrackService::class.java))
        }
    }

    fun checkDrawOverlayPermission(): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true
        }
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + packageName))
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                //startService(Intent(this, TrackService::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I go to the windows (programmatically with this code), I can't grant the access.

Do someone got this problem, or as a fix?

Comment: "when I go to the windows (programmatically with this code), I can't grant the access" -- what does this mean? Does your app request the appropriate permission in the manifest?

Comment: Thanks, I went to check the manifest and found that I forgot the permission...

Comment: You can add an answer to your question and mark it. It would be more usuful than reading whole post.

Comment: You should answer the question below, not update the question with your solution.